# spark.read.json() how to read files using a dynamic year parameter

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark

I have an s3 directory that looks something like this:

```
my-data/data-events/year/month/day/hour/file.json
```

I have the years 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021 and 2022. I want to read in everything from 2020 onward. How would I do that without moving files around?
I currently have my read function like this, which reads in all files:

```
spark.read.json("s3a://my-data/data-events/*/*/*/*/*")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about `spark.read.json("s3a://my-data/data-events/{2020,2021,2022}/*/*/*/*")`

to make it dynamic based on current_year

```
from datetime import datetime

current_year = datetime.now().year
years_to_query = ",".join([str(x) for x in range(2020, current_year + 1)])
f"s3a://my-data/data-events/{{{years_to_query}}}/*/*/*/*"
```

Also if you have partitioned your data, e.g:
the path would have been my-data/data-events/year=YYYY/month=MM/day=DD/hour=HH/file.json you could have spark.read.json("s3a://my-data/data-events") and then `.filter(col("year") >= '2020')`, this filter would have been run against the folders paths and not by looking into the jsons themselves.

Comment: But what about when 2023 inevitably comes by? How do I account for that without hard coding it? Is there a way to do not 2018, 2019?

Comment: I've updated my answer with a string updated to current date, what do you think?